# SQL Query Adding Complex Conditions from a Table

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle

I have a long list (or a table of 3 to 4 columns of data) which simultaneously needs to be satisfied in a query, like below:

```
A    B   C
x1   y1  z1
x2   y2   z2
x3   y3   z3
.
.
.
xn    yn   zn
```

Is there a way I can create an expression/function etc or separate list etc which I can have  which can be called into the SQL Query (instead of explicitly writing it):

So assuming, I have this list as a matrix/list in a table X (local) and I can use

and I can use a sample SQL query something like

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE B
WHERE CONDITION  IN  ROWS OF TABLE X
```

Just to add here, that I am using python driver to get data via database and the table X (I have it locally on my drive) which I have is which I created locally.

Comment: . . Don't call something a table unless it is in the database.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: What I mean was that I have the table X as a file locally on my PC. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: To clarify the question as pointed out by Gordan:   No I was not asking for the python code. I asked how can I create a compact query  filter with the WHERE clause where the condition is being from a local table. Say based on the table I provided if each of the conditions in each row are met like ( x1 & y1 & z1   or x2 & y2 & z2  or x3 & y3 & z3  ..)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking for python code.

Using a simple in-memory [SQLite](https://www.python-course.eu/sql_python.php) db you can achieve this. See how use Sqlite db with python here. [How to work with sqlite3 and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209868/how-to-work-with-sqlite3-and-python).

Considering your example where we have list of data.

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("company.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()

staff_data = [ ("William", "Shakespeare", "m", "1961-10-25"),
               ("Frank", "Schiller", "m", "1955-08-17"),
               ("Jane", "Wall", "f", "1989-03-14") ]

for p in staff_data:
    format_str = """INSERT INTO employee (staff_number, fname, lname, gender, birth_date)
    VALUES (NULL, "{first}", "{last}", "{gender}", "{birthdate}");"""

    sql_command = format_str.format(first=p[0], last=p[1], gender=p[2], birthdate = p[3])
    cursor.execute(sql_command)
```

See more [here](https://www.python-course.eu/sql_python.php).

.

Comment: No I was not asking for the python code. I asked how can I create a compact query  filter with the WHERE clause where the condition is being from a local table. Say based on the table I provided if each of the conditions in each row are met like ( x1 & y1 & z1   or x2 & y2 & z2  or x3 & y3 & z3  ..)