# How to connect a file with extention .sqlt to python?

Tags: python, sqlite

How to connect a file with extention .sqlt to python? All sources say about files with .db extention.

For example in R language I'm able to connect this way:
dbase <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "XYZ.sqlite")

just I need to make such connection in Python.

I'm a beginner, will be grateful for your support.

Comment: Does this help? [How to work with sqlite3 and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209868/how-to-work-with-sqlite3-and-python)

Comment: Extension doesn't care, try to open with `sqlite3.connect` and fetch some records, it should work it it's a sqlite3 binary file